# Which definition is used for the verb "to edge" here?

Tags: word-usage

Regarding [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/pound-falls-report-johnson-planning-003244267.html), there is a paragraph saying,

> Against the yen, the dollar traded at 109.56 yen <JPY=>, up 0.05% from late U.S. levels, having gained 0.15% on Monday to ***edge*** near six-month high of 109.73 hit on Dec. 2.

Which definition is used for the bold italic verb to "edge" to make the sentence understandable?

From Merriam

> transitive verb

> 1
> :  to give an edge to
>
> <hurt resentment edged his wife's voice — G. G. Carter>

> 2
> obsolete :  to set (one's teeth) on edge

> 3
> a (1) :  to finish (an edge) with a binding, band, strip, or trimming
>
>
> (2) :  to decorate an edge of (something, such as a book) (3) :  to level an edge of (a rafter); also :  to square an edge of
> b :  to serve as a border to :  fringe
> <warehouses and terminals edge the 25-mile waterfront — L. A. Borah>
> :  be on an edge of
> <grew up in a community still edging the wilderness — H. M. Kallen>
> <now edging sixty, he retains all his vigor>

> 4
> archaic :  to urge or egg on

> 5
> :  to move gradually or by pressing forward edgewise
> <edged his master out of hearing — George Meredith>
>
> :  force (as from a position) by the application of pressure
>
> displace
> <machine-made muslins and calicoes have been edging out native-made muslins — John Murra>

> 6
> a :  to strike (a bowled ball) in cricket with the edge of the bat
> b :  to incline (a ski) sideways so that one edge cuts into the surface of the snow

> 7
> :  to defeat or surpass (an opponent or rival) by a small margin
> <Joe Cimino of Malden shot 75 and edged Jeff Daniels of Hooksett, N.H., by a stroke to win a Boston Amateur Golf Society tournament … — Jim McCabe and Michael Vega, Boston Globe, 1 Aug. 2002>
> — often + out
> < … Miller edged out Mattingly by 50 percent to 46 percent. — John B. Judis, New Republic, 18 Nov. 2002>
> <Since 1995, Wisconsin has consistently edged out Massachusetts to claim the rank of top cranberry producer in the United States. — Cynthia Berlin, Geography, Winter 2002>

> intransitive verb
> :  to move in one direction by degrees
> <edged over the open plains toward the western extremities of the country — Oscar Handlin>
>
> :  move edgeways
> <began to edge along the front of the bureau — Berton Roueché>

Comment: *"If someone or something edges somewhere, they move very slowly in that direction."* - Collins. It's the 5th one on your list.

Comment: In currency trading or the stock market, to edge means to come close to. And it should be to edge near **as** six-month high of X.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the comment by @AIQ, the definition was like 5 (like 5, meaning, kind of).

I appreciate his comment answer.